# Cursor position centered and in the middle for javaFX TextArea

Tags: css, javafx-2

I want to have my cursor of a JavaFX TextArea horizontally and vertically centered. I already tried using CSS with attributes like

```
-fx-text-alignment: center;
```

or

```
-fx-text-origin: bottom;
```

but it didn't work :-(.
Can somebody tell me if and maybe how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-fx-alignment: center

Read this documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea

Comment: Well, thank you. Now I use a TextField with this property instead of a TextArea.